# iOS 10 Getting Push Notification Alert Twice in iPhone

Tags: ios, iphone, apple-push-notifications

[image]

I am facing issue in iOS 10 and iPhone. Getting push notification alert twice. Please review below video.

I write similar code in willPresentNotification and didReceiveNotificationResponse notification delegate method.is there any change for me to do code changes in both method because I am not facing problem in iPad.

Your help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

In `iOS 10` we need to call the `UNUserNotificationCenter` in appDelegate `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` method.

You must import the `UserNotifications.framework` and add the `UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate` in `Appdelegate`

**AppDelegate.h**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <UserNotifications/UserNotifications.h>

@interface AppDelegate : UIResponder <UIApplicationDelegate,UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate>

@property (strong, nonatomic) UIWindow *window;

@end
```

AppDelegate.m

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
   if([[[UIDevice currentDevice]systemVersion]floatValue]<10.0)
   {
      [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerUserNotificationSettings:[UIUserNotificationSettings settingsForTypes:(UIUserNotificationTypeSound |    UIUserNotificationTypeAlert | UIUserNotificationTypeBadge) categories:nil]];
      [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotifications];
   }
   else
   {
      UNUserNotificationCenter *center = [UNUserNotificationCenter currentNotificationCenter];
      center.delegate = self;
      [center requestAuthorizationWithOptions:(UNAuthorizationOptionSound | UNAuthorizationOptionAlert | UNAuthorizationOptionBadge) completionHandler:^(BOOL granted, NSError * _Nullable error)
      {
         if( !error )
         {
             [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotifications];
             NSLog( @"Push registration success." );
         }
         else
         {
             NSLog( @"Push registration FAILED" );
             NSLog( @"ERROR: %@ - %@", error.localizedFailureReason, error.localizedDescription );
             NSLog( @"SUGGESTIONS: %@ - %@", error.localizedRecoveryOptions, error.localizedRecoverySuggestion );  
         }  
     }];  
   }
  return YES;
}
```

For get information in Swift [See this](https://swifting.io/blog/2016/08/22/23-notifications-in-ios-10/)

Comment: Yes I implemented iOS 10 code and It is working fine on iPad but not on iPhone 6s with iOS 10. I am getting alert twice if possible please review video.

Comment: @PareshVasoya can you check in your didFinishLaunchingWithOptions method you'r not calling "registerUserNotificationSettings" twice.

Comment: Yes I checked that twice but I registered only once in didFinishLaunchingWithOptions method for iOS 10.

Comment: @PareshVasoya The thing that I'm concerned about is that Apple suggest to register for remote notifications on every application launch since the token may change (read here: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Chapters/IPhoneOSClientImp.html) Calling registerUserNotificationSettings only once goes against Apple's suggestion here.

Comment: Please review attached screenshot. I registered only once and on iPad iOS 10 it is working fine getting only one alert when app is in forground and on iPhone getting issue.

Comment: @PareshVasoya Can you try with register once in didFinishLaunchingWithOptions once. Do not call it other time while you open the app.

Comment: @PareshVasoya No brother i am talking about you have to call  "registerUserNotificationSettings" only once. Not everytime while you open the app.

Comment: Hi I get the solution which is content-available issue in payload

Answer (score 0):

I found the mistake. I was writing the same code in both delegate methods and getting content-available: 1 parameter in payload which caused the issue where both methods fire in foreground. This lead to app displaying two alerts for a single push notification.